# Let $\phi : \mathbb Q(\sqrt2)\to \mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$ be an isomorphism. Show that if $\phi(1) = 1$, then $\phi(a) = a$ for all $a \in \mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, splitting-field, ring-isomorphism

Let $\phi : \mathbb Q(\sqrt2) \to \mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$ be an isomorphism.

Show that if $\phi(1) = 1$, then $\phi(a) = a$ for all $a \in \mathbb Q$

My attempt:

$\phi(1) = \phi(a.a^{-1}) = \phi(a).\phi(a^{-1}) = 1$. Then $\phi(a) = \phi^{-1}(a^{-1})$.

I'm stuck here. Can anyone tell me how to continue this?

Comment: Use \to for $\to$ instead of -> :)

Comment: Prove that $\phi(n)=n$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$, so $$\phi(\frac{n}{m})=\phi(n)\phi(\frac{1}{m})=\frac{\phi(n)}{\phi(m)}=\frac{n}{m}$$

Comment: $\phi(1)=1$ is not a necessary assumption, It's always true for an isomorphism of fields.

Comment: $\phi(a)\phi(a^{-1})=1$ means $\phi(a^{-1}) = \phi(a)^{-1}$ (or $\phi(a) = \phi(a^{-1})^{-1}$) instead of $\phi(a) = \phi^{-1}(a^{-1})$.

Comment: Alternately, $\phi(1)=\phi(1^2)=\phi(1)^2$.